# Order of operation in HashSet's method add()

Tags: java, hash, hashset

I'm facing a bit of a problem when it comes to the method add of HashSet. Even after reading the source code for it [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.add%28java.lang.Object%29), I don't really understand what is going on.

What exactly does the method do? What is the order of actions it takes in terms of calls to hashCode and equals?

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet` is just a `HashMap` where the value is an `Object`.
So `add` just adds the element to the backing hashmap. Adding an element to a hashmap means use the hashCode to figure out where it should be placed. The `equals` is used to while determining if the key that we are trying to add is already there and then the value should just be updated

Comment: *"where the value is a boolean"* - Wrong

Comment: So, supposing that the Object we're trying to add to the HashSet has a certain HashCode. However, there is already a value "bucketed" to that HashCode. If the new Object we're trying to add is not equal (in terms of the equals() method) to the Object previously "bucketed" is replaced with the one we're trying to add?

Comment: @PedroRibeiro Research helps: [How does a Java HashMap handle different objects with the same hash code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6493605)

Comment: @Tom:Wow! I was 100% sure it was a `Boolean` and not an `Object`. Why did I have that impression??

Comment: @PedroRibeiro: If they are not equal and have the same hash then it is added to the list that belongs to that bucket. You should read about the internals. It is a linked list per bucket